# How i can use this OpenCV code for face detection using python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I founded this code on the web, I'd like to use it for detect my face.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Face Detection Test (OpenCV)
#
# thanks to:
# http://japskua.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/detecting-eyes-with-python-opencv
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

import cv
import time
import Image

def DetectFace(image, faceCascade):

    min_size = (20,20)
    image_scale = 2
    haar_scale = 1.1
    min_neighbors = 3
    haar_flags = 0

    # Allocate the temporary images
    grayscale = cv.CreateImage((image.width, image.height), 8, 1)
    smallImage = cv.CreateImage(
            (
                cv.Round(image.width / image_scale),
                cv.Round(image.height / image_scale)
            ), 8 ,1)

    # Convert color input image to grayscale
    cv.CvtColor(image, grayscale, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

    # Scale input image for faster processing
    cv.Resize(grayscale, smallImage, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR)

    # Equalize the histogram
    cv.EqualizeHist(smallImage, smallImage)

    # Detect the faces
    faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(
            smallImage, faceCascade, cv.CreateMemStorage(0),
            haar_scale, min_neighbors, haar_flags, min_size
        )

    # If faces are found
    if faces:
        for ((x, y, w, h), n) in faces:
            # the input to cv.HaarDetectObjects was resized, so scale the
            # bounding box of each face and convert it to two CvPoints
            pt1 = (int(x * image_scale), int(y * image_scale))
            pt2 = (int((x + w) * image_scale), int((y + h) * image_scale))
            cv.Rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, cv.RGB(255, 0, 0), 5, 8, 0)

    return image

#----------
# M A I N
#----------

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
#capture = cv.CaptureFromFile("test.avi")

faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
#faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")
#faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
#faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml")

while (cv.WaitKey(15)==-1):
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    image = DetectFace(img, faceCascade)
    cv.ShowImage("face detection test", image)

cv.ReleaseCapture(capture)
```

I'd like to use it for my test, but when I try to execute it I recive this error:

```
root@aetas:~/Scrivania# python riconoscimentofacciale.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "riconoscimentofacciale.py", line 63, in <module>
    faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
TypeError: OpenCV returned NULL
```

Someone have the solution?

**The question below is resolved. The solution is to create one folder that contain script and the folder haarcascades(with XML file).
Thanks to DineMartine and Dominique**

Comment: Do you have this file in your directory ? haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

Comment: I have the impression from the mentioned website that there is the source code, and there are the configuration files. It seems you have downloaded the source code but not the configuration files.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with the solution that I find with your help!